# Get column name in a SSIS script task

Tags: ssis, integration

I need to get back a column name in order to fill an error message.
I'm using a synchronous script task and I have my `Input0Buffer Row` with all my rows available, but I'm searching for something like `Row.MyColumn.ColumnName`

Does anybody know something about that ?

Comment: http://agilebi.com/jwelch/2007/10/21/address-columns-generically-in-a-script-task/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120634/what-is-the-simple-way-to-find-the-column-name-from-lineageid-in-ssis/8124022#8124022

Comment: Thanks for your Links, in fact the line this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection[0].Name return me the Column name for the first column. I know that I have to specify which Column Name I want back in InputColumnCollection[N] but I was searching for something more generic.